# How to bind ListBox ItemsSource to a ViewModel property (which is a Collection) programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, data-binding

I have always been binding ListBox ItemsSource in XAML. How can I do the binding in c# code from the code behind file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps

1. Name the listbox control in XAML so the C# compiler can access it via that name.
2. Load the listbox by its itemssource such in the page initializer/constructor.

   ```
    myListBox.ItemsSource = myListName;
   ```

Comment: It works if its done in page initializer or constructor but it doesn't work when we do it anywhere like button click. Any ideas ?

Comment: Ah got the bugger ...removed the existing binding in XAML now it works

Answer (score 1):

This is how i set Bindings from code if it can be of any help:

```
            //chk = CheckBox object
            //item = the object in my model on the Window/User control datacontext
            //IsChecked = name of the property inside item that I bind to the checkbox

            Binding myBinding = new Binding("IsChecked");
            myBinding.Source = item;

            //If your property should be not a boolean you can set a converter
            //In this sample I have a String to boolean converter if needed
            //myBinding.Converter = new StringToBoolConverter();

            //Set the binding mode, oneway, twoway or whatever
            myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            //Indicate to the binding that the Property Change is triggering and update
            myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

            //Set the binding in the Checkbox object on my window
            chk.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, myBinding);
```

However if you need to set just the ItemSource of a Listbox you don't need to build the binding but you can simply give the Listbox a Name in XAML

```
<Listbox Name=MyListbox....>
```

And then in code behind set the ItemSource property to your model property:

```
MyListbox.ItemSource = mymodel.MyListProperty
```